# Google Calendar .ics import issue

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

If I export a Google Calendar event that has same `start time` and `end time`, in the exported `ics` file `end date` and `end time` don't show up.

This is the exported code of that event.

`BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20191119T113000
DTSTAMP:20191118T112421
UID:0ffjlmpcarr13se1n2qkgv68iq@google.com
CREATED:20191118T112249
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20191118T112249
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:one day only startTime
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT`

Then, if I import this same event to Google Calendar, the imported event has an `end time` which is 1 hour later than the `start time`, when in the original event, they are the same. In this case 12:30.

How can I import event with `start time` only.

Comment: Where did you get that event from? In Google Calendar, you have to specify an end time/end date when creating an event, no matter if it's with the API or via UI.

Comment: You are right, but when I export my calendar from google calendar, this event appears without end date and end time, and when I import the same file to google calendar it has not only the start time but also end time 12:30.Do I have to set manually end time?

Comment: Have you checked the end time in the original calendar event? If you use the UI to create it and you specify a start time (that is, you don't create an all day event), by default the end time will be 1 hour later. How are you exporting this event?

Comment: I have created the event and have exported the calendar via UI. In my calendar the default end time is 30min, but I set it like start time(diff 0min).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. I [created a bug for you](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144826660) in Google Issue Tracker. You can click the star on the top left in this page if you want to keep track of this issue.

As a workaround, I can think of different options:

(1) You can add the corresponding field `DTEND` in the exported `ics` file, with the same value as your `DTSTART`:

`DTEND:20191119T113000`

In this way, when you import it to the Calendar, it has the correct `end time`.

(2) Depending on why are you doing this import/export and what you want to accomplish, maybe using [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/overview) could be useful for you? For example, with the API you could find the imported events and [edit their end time accordingly](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update).

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Yes, I have done as you said, I added `DTEND` in the `ics` file. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Also, remember to [accept answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that are helpful to you as this community relies on this to share knowledge to other users.